# How do I refresh when I reselect the tab I'm on in my bottom navigation bar?

Tags: java, android, parsing, android-fragments, bottomnavigationview

So this is the code I have for my bottom navigation bar, in my tabs I'm retrieving data from parse
my question is what do I put inside my  `BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemReselectedListener` in order for the tab that I reselect to reload/refresh
would very much appreciate any help!

````
    final Fragment fragment1 = new HomeFragment();
    final Fragment fragment2 = new UsersFragment();
    final Fragment fragment3 = new ProfileFragment();
    final Fragment fragment4 = new SettingsFragment();
    final FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    Fragment active = fragment1;

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if(ParseUser.getCurrentUser() != null){
            Intent a = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
            a.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
            a.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            startActivity(a);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_home);


        BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView = findViewById(R.id.bottom_navigation);
        bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(navigationItemSelectedListener);
     bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemReselectedListener(navigationItemReselectedListener);


        fm.beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragment_container, fragment4, "4").hide(fragment4).commit();
        fm.beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragment_container, fragment3, "3").hide(fragment3).commit();
        fm.beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragment_container, fragment2, "2").hide(fragment2).commit();
        fm.beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragment_container,fragment1, "1").commit();

    }

    private BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener navigationItemSelectedListener = new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull @NotNull MenuItem item) {

            switch (item.getItemId()){
                case R.id.nav_home:
                    fm.beginTransaction().hide(active).show(fragment1).commit();
                    active = fragment1;
                    return true;
                case R.id.nav_list:
                    fm.beginTransaction().hide(active).show(fragment2).commit();
                    active = fragment2;
                    return true;
                case R.id.nav_profile:
                    fm.beginTransaction().hide(active).show(fragment3).commit();
                    active = fragment3;
                    return true;
                case R.id.nav_settings:
                    fm.beginTransaction().hide(active).show(fragment4).commit();
                    active = fragment4;
                    return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    };

    private BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemReselectedListener navigationItemReselectedListener = new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemReselectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onNavigationItemReselected(@NonNull @NotNull MenuItem item) {

        }
    };
}```
````

Answer (score 0):

So you are calling the fragment through bottom navigation bar
So for every selection of an item in the bottom navigation yo do want to refresh the fragment
Do use attach() and detach() method while beginning the transaction. It refreshes each  time

Comment: Sorry I don't quite understand you
someone on another question recommended me to do the following
`FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
fragmentTransaction.detach(active);
fragmentTransaction.attach(active);
fragmentTransaction.commit();`
sadly it did not work
is that what you meant?

Comment: Yeah . Have you tried it inside onNavigtionItemSelected? In each case!?

Comment: no, I tried putting it inside onNavigtionItemReselected in each case, why would I put it inside onNavigtionItemSelected?
how my code works is that I when I change tabs, the content of the previous tab remains so when I change back to it I'm back where I left off
what I want to do is that when I'm in lets say the home tab, and press it again, I want it to reload

Comment: I do understand.. but  I even didn't come across these suitations . But can  give you some references just what I do know ...do try https://www.py4u.net/discuss/633629

Comment: no worries at all, thank you for the help, much appreciated!